# Fail2ban ban is not working as expected [DDOS]

Tags: linux, security, firewall, ddos, fail2ban

I have this jail:

```
##To stop DOS attack from remote host.
[http-get-dos]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = http-get-dos
logpath  = /usr/local/nginx/localhost-access.log
maxretry = 100
findtime = 300
bantime = 6000
action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
```

---

```
Status for the jail: http-get-dos
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 18
|  |- Total failed:     99871
|  `- File list:        /usr/local/nginx/localhost-access.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 2
   |- Total banned:     5
   `- Banned IP list:   94.60.20.166 193.112.177.8
```

---

However, after running `fail2ban-client status http-get-dos`, where the IP is marked as banned, I am still getting a lot of incoming requests from the banned IP that will cause high CPU usage:

```
193.112.177.8 - - [01/Jul/2019:17:48:59 +0100] "GET /companies/xxx HTTP/1.1" 200 18935 "https://example.com/companies/xxx" "shelby/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
193.112.177.8 - - [01/Jul/2019:17:48:59 +0100] "GET /companies/xxx HTTP/1.1" 200 18935 "https://example.com/companies/xxx" "asdfgh/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
193.112.177.8 - - [01/Jul/2019:17:49:00 +0100] "GET /companies/xxx HTTP/1.1" 200 18935 "https://example.com/companies/xxx" "tigger/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
...
```

Now, If I do:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 193.112.177.8 -j DROP
```

I don't see more requests in logs from this IP. The question is, why the ban from fail2ban it not working like the rule above?

Comment: What is the current state of your firewall?

Comment: @MichaelHampton what do you mean by current state? run iptables -L?

Comment: You also need to include `-n` and `-v`, otherwise the listing is incomplete.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have both IPS banned in Chain INPUT, but I think that is due the manual ban. Also the fail2ban ban already expired, so, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your site is `https` and that's why you still get requests because you are not banning `https` but only `http`

Proper action is

```
action = iptables-multiport[name=HTTP, port="http,https", protocol=tcp]
```

Comment: Or just `port=%(port)` because there is `port = http,https` in the definition.